# Mysql2::Error (Access denied for user 'b00120fa21c0f6'@'ip-10-139-25-93.ec2.internal' (using password: YES)):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql, heroku

**・環境**
heroku
ClearDB MySQL

RailsアプリをHerokuで動かしているのですが、作業中に「We're sorry, but something went wrong.」が表示され、アプリが動かなくなってしまいました。
Herokuのログを見ると、以下のエラー文がありました。
調べたのですが解決方法が分からずアドバイス頂きたいです。
何卒宜しくお願い致します。

**エラー文**
 Mysql2::Error (Access denied for user 'b00120fa21c0f6'@'ip-10-139-25-93.ec2.internal' (using password: YES)):

**database.yml**
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
  template: template0

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/52803

Comment: [ClearDB MySQL \| Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cleardb#configuring-your-ruby-application-to-use-cleardb)
の作業は終わられているのでしょうか？

Comment: はい、ご教示頂いた作業は行いました。今回のエラーはシステムの作業中に突然発生しました。user 'b00120fa21c0f6'のパスワードが正しく設定されていない？のが原因なのかと思いますが、DBにもアクセスできない状況になってしまっており、どのように解決すればよいのか分からない状況です。

Answer (score 0):

どのような作業中ですか？
database.ymlにはrootのパスワードが無いので、rootに対するエラーならばrailsでの作業(例えば rake db:createとか)に思えますが、b00120fa21c0f6に対するエラーなのでMySQLへの直接の作業でしょうか？
もしそうですとMySQLへのユーザ設定が足りないように思われます。